# how to return 0 instead of null with 'in' operator

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have hree tables:

1. **text: text in lines**
2. **trigram: trigram of all text lines**
3. **text_trigram: trigrams that a text line contains, intermediate table**

When I execute this:

```
select count(coalesce(text_id,0)), text_id 
from text_trigram 
where text_id in (1, 2, 3) 
and trigram_id = 1 
group by text_id;
```

it came out with the result without having the `null` result which I want it to be `0`:

```
count|text_id
1       1 
1       2
```

This is what I except to have:

```
count|text_id 
 1       1 
 1       2
 0       3
```

Further more I want to execute something like this:

```
select count(coalesce(text_id,0)), text_id 
from text_trigram 
where text_id in (1, 2, 3) 
and trigram_id in (1, 2, 3) 
group by text_id;
```

```
count|text_id|trigram_id 
   1       1        1
   1       1        2
   0       1        3
   1       2        1
   1       2        2
   1       2        3
   0       3        1
```

it is possible? or is it wrong using `in` operator?

Comment: Your query only returns one column, not two.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for pointing it out, I revised it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion here is that you are assuming there is a null for `text_id=3`, but actually there is *just no row that matches*. Consider this simplified version:

```
select *
from text_trigram 
where text_id in (3)
```

This will not return any rows if there is no entry with `text_id=3`; it won't fabricate a row with a bunch of nulls in.

In order to force a row to exist even if there is no matching data, you can create a table expression containing those IDs, e.g.

```
select * from
(
    values (1), (2), (3)
) as required_ids ( text_id );
```

Then `LEFT JOIN` your data, so you get `NULL` where there is no matching data:

```
select *
from
    (
        values (1), (2), (3)
    ) as required_ids ( text_id )
left join text_trigram 
    on text_trigram.text_id = required_ids.text_id;
```

To get to your first query, note two things:

- `count` ignores nulls, so `count(text_trigram.text_id)` will only count rows where a match was found in the `text_trigram` table
- any extra conditions need to be in the `on` clause of the `left join`, so that they eliminate rows from `text_trigram`, not from the whole query

```
select count(text_trigram.text_id), required_ids.text_id
from
    (
        values (1), (2), (3)
    ) as required_ids ( text_id )
left join text_trigram 
    on text_trigram.text_id = required_ids.text_id
    and text_trigram.trigram_id = 1
group by text_id
order by text_id;
```

Changing this to every permutation of `text_id` and `trigram_id` would just involve an extra table expression and a `CROSS JOIN`:

```
select required_text_ids.text_id, required_trigram_ids.trigram_id, count(text_trigram.text_id)
from
    (
        values (1), (2), (3)
    ) as required_text_ids( text_id )
cross join
    (
        values (1), (2), (3)
    ) as required_trigram_ids( trigram_id )
left join text_trigram 
    on text_trigram.text_id = required_text_ids.text_id
    and text_trigram.trigram_id = required_trigram_ids.trigram_id
group by required_text_ids.text_id, required_trigram_ids.trigram_id
order by required_text_ids.text_id, required_trigram_ids.trigram_id;
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. But in this way, the constraint of `trigram_id` is missing, if I add it with a where condition, then the result is the same without `0`. Should there be actually no matching for certain `trigram_id`?

Comment: @heisthere Ah, I see what you mean. The trick is to add it to the `on` clause of the `left join` rather than the main `where`; I've updated the answer.

Comment: but since it's grouped by `text_id`, the `required_text_ids.text_id` and `required_trigram_ids.trigram_id` can't be selected right?

Comment: @heisthere Sorry, that's just a mistake on my part. If you want to count how many entries there are for each combination, you need both columns in the group by clause.

Comment: Hey, I found if there is no match found after a certain position, then the values after this position would not be showed, the continuous repeated 0 would be only one instead. I mean, if the result should be like this `1 1 0 1 1` than it works well, but if it should be `1 1 1 0 0` than this solution simply return `1 1 1`. What could I do? :/

Comment: @heisthere I can't see how that would be the case based on that query, because there's nothing to give meaning to "before" and "after"; in fact, thinking about it, it doesn't even have an `order by` clause to guarantee that results will be in any particular order, which I'll fix in the example. I suspect you're doing something when displaying the result that's accidentally hiding the extra results.

Comment: I am sorry, I was wrong. The result was that, it returns `1`s, if matches found, and one single `0` for all no match.

Comment: I think it was because `group by`, if there are `NULL`s, than one single `NULL` comes out, so the result has only one single `0`?

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation if every `text_id` has at least one trigram:

```
select text_id, sum(case when trigram_id = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from text_trigram
where text_id in (1, 2, 3) 
group by text_id
```

Or you can use a `left join`:

```
select t.text_id, count(tt.trigram_id) as cnt
from text t left join
     text_trigram tt
     on tt.text_id = t.text_id and tt.trigram_id = 1
where t.text_id in (1, 2, 3) 
group by t.text_id
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but with the first solution, ```trigram_id = 1``` since lose its function. the result is exactlly the same as ```select count(*) from text_trigram where text_id = 1;```

Comment: The data has 1,5 billion rows, so I try to avoid using any Join, but I haven't test any yet, does that make sense to avoid using join?

Comment: @heisthere . . . The second solution should do what you want then.

Comment: the second solution didn't work either, it showed the result exactly like what I just had :/

Comment: Is "text_id" = 3 not in the`text` table?

Comment: it did. But as @IMSoP pointted out, there was actually no match but not null