# sqlite: How to return 0 when no row found within `in` operator

Tags: sql, sqlite, count

I asked a same question before, it was answered and solved using `psql` [how to return 0 instead of null with 'in' operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59163415/how-to-return-0-instead-of-null-with-in-operator). 
This was the idea of the solution, using a built list instead `in`:

```
select * from
(
    values (1), (2), (3)
) as required_ids ( text_id );
```

But I somehow have to rewrite it by `sqlite3`, the problem is that, there is no `values(...)` thing in `sqlite3`, so I cannot build a list instead of `in(...)`. Does anyone know how to do that? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `select`/`union all`:

```
select *
from (select 1 as text_id union all select 2 union all select 3) required_id
```

Answer (score 0):

> there is no values(...) thing in sqlite3

Of course **there is**, since version 3.15:

```
select * from (values (1), (2), (3));
```

You can refer to the returned column as `column1`.
Result:

```
> | column1 |
> | ------: |
> |       1 |
> |       2 |
> |       3 |
```

Or inside a `CTE`:

```
with cte(val) as (
  select * from (values (1), (2), (3))
)
select * from cte
```

Result:

```
> | val |
> | --: |
> |   1 |
> |   2 |
> |   3 |
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=4deb4efa1d87a09449d379af45d7321f).

Comment: Thank you for the knowledge you brought. My version is 3.7.17, which runs on a remote sever that I cannot upgrade. So..

Comment: SQLite's most recent version is 3.31.1 So even 3.15.0 (2016-10-14) is considered old.